# Why wasn’t anyone suspicious about the Diggory’s family tree?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child, delphini

Tried to formulate a question as neutral as possible to avoid spoilers about CC, but here they come!
Leave now if you haven't read/seen/finished it ;)

So my actual question is rather:

> Why didn't anyone find it weird that Amos Diggory had a niece?

I mean, the British wizarding world is kind of small. All over the books, we can see that most people are related or friends or friends of relatives, or neighbours of relatives or colleagues or something.
The result is that almost everybody knows (at least has heard of) everybody.

> “The pure-blood families are all interrelated,” said Sirius.
>   *(Order of The Phoenix, Chapter 6, The noble and most ancient house of Black)*

Even baby Malfoy had heard of the Weasleys, even if their family are not really friends:

> No need to ask who you are. My father
>   told me all the Weasleys have red hair, freckles, and more children than
>   they can afford.
>   *(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 6, The Journey from Platform nine and three quarters)*

For instance, the Weasley's : Arthur and Molly knew very well Amos, since he lived not far away from them and worked with Arthur:

> "Amos!" said Mr. Weasley, smiling as he strode over to the man who had shouted. The rest of them followed.
>   Mr. Weasley was shaking hands with a ruddy-faced wizard with a scrubby brown beard, who was holding a moldy-looking old boot in his other hand.
>   "This is Amos Diggory, everyone," said Mr. Weasley. "He works for the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures. And I think you know his son, Cedric?"
>   *(Goblet of fire, Chapter 6, The portkey)*
>
> Mr. Diggory’s head looked around at Mrs. Weasley.
>   “Sorry about this, Molly,” it said, more calmly, “bothering you so early and everything…but Arthur’s the only one who can get Mad-Eye off, and Mad-Eye’s supposed to be starting his new job today. Why he had to choose last night…”
>   “Never mind, Amos,” said Mrs. Weasley. “Sure you won’t have a bit of toast or anything before you go?”
>   “Oh go on, then,” said Mr. Diggory.
>   Mrs. Weasley took a piece of buttered toast from a stack on the kitchen table, put it into the fire tongs, and transferred it into Mr. Diggory’s mouth.
>   *(Goblet of fire, Chapter 11, Aboard the Hogwarts Express)*

Surely they would have known Amos and his wife were only child.

In such a village atmosphere, how many children did Cedric's grand-parents have had was probably public information.

So how comes no one ever wondered how Amos could have a niece?

The Weasleys (Ron or Ginny), the people working at St Oswald’s Home for Old Witches and Wizards, the other residents of the hospice, the people visiting them…

Amos himself was Confunded alright, but how comes no one ever went “Hello Amos, how are you today? You’re saying this young person is your niece? How is this possible, I thought you didn't had any sibling?”

Comment: 1. Cursed Child is silly.  2. Yeah it should be odd but seeing as Cedric had never been to see Weasleys outside of Hogwarts as suggested by "I think you know his son, Cedric?" that means the relations were cordial but not too close. In that kind of relations, you don't really know someone's nieces and nephews.

Comment: Yes, I just don't think the Diggorys and Weasleys are that close. And I don't think old people home staff are that informed about extended family members. And would you contront them? "I've never heard of you - you can't be who you say you are!"

Comment: Yes in our Muggle world I agree, but this world is so small, I'm quite sure even when you don't know very well someone, you still know "he's Mr.X and MrsX's son, you know the ones who work at that department, they've got 2 children" or something like that. Like in a tiny village! And so I can't believe no one realised there was no sibling in these families who could have produced a niece...

Answer (score 3):

The Sr. Diggorys could very well have had brothers and sisters.

Harry did not grow up in the wizarding world till he arrive at Hogwarts and even then doesn't have his own parents to make introduction to other adults, find out about family tree's ect.

Ginny on the other hand would have much more of the information but perhaps the Weasleys didn't care to discuss the family trees of friends, perhaps the Weasleys were no more then work colleagues.

Other possibilities, Mr.Diggory's supposed brother sister(inlaw) could be living abroad, could have married a foreign wizard/witch, Delphi even says she didn't go to Hogwarts

> DELPHI: I was — unwell — as a child — for a few years. Other people got to go — I did not.

A simple yet effective cover to deter further questions, and a very good excuse for why no one knows her.

Dont forget, Harry just meets her for less then a minute in passing, he may not have even talked to Ginny about it. They don't put the pieces together about her till the end of the book, after they go talk to Mr.Diggory. Harry was more upset with Mr.Diggory bringing up Cedric's death to care about some supposed niece/caregiver.

Hell Mr. Diggory is slightly unhinged he is in a "home" after all, he could simply be calling his caregiver niece because hes crazy or out of affection, like old people do.